# How do I fix syntax error after "case" block

Tags: verilog

I am trying to make a 4-bit full adder using a NEXYS 4 DDR in vivado 2017.4 using Verilog. The full adder is working perfectly, and now I am setting the anodes that drive the 7-seg display on the board. I used a `case` block, and the counter is used to slow down the signal. I am getting a `syntax error near end` error at the `end` at the end of the third `always` block.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module FA(
    input clk_i,

    input [3:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    input C_in,
    output [3:0] S,
    output C_o
    );
    reg [19:0] counter;
    reg [7:0] anode;
    wire [0:0] MSB;
    reg [4:0] C;
    integer i;
    genvar k;
    reg temp [4:0];
    always@(*)
    begin
    if(C_in)
    begin
    C[0] = 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
    C[0] = 1'b0;
    end
    for(i=0;i<=3;i=i+1)
    begin
    temp[i] = A[i] + B[i] + C[i];
    if((A[i] && B[i]) || (A[i] && C[i]) || (B[i] && C[i]))
    begin
    C[i+1] = 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
    C[i+1] = 1'b0;
    end
    end

    end
    for(k=0;k<=3;k=k+1)
    begin
    assign S[k] = temp[k];
    end
    assign C_o = C[4];

    always@(posedge clk_i)
    begin
    counter <= counter + 1;
    end

    assign MSB = counter[19];

    always@(*)
    begin
        case(MSB)
            1'b0: begin
            anode = 8'b11101111;
                  end
            1'b1: begin
            anode = 8'b11011111;
                  end
    end //this line gives me the error



endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `endcase` keyword:

```
always@(*)
begin
    case(MSB)
        1'b0: begin
        anode = 8'b11101111;
              end
        1'b1: begin
        anode = 8'b11011111;
              end
    endcase
end
```

Using a case statement for a 1-bit select is overkill.

```
wire [7:0] anode = (MSB) ? 8'b1101_1111 : 8'b1110_1111;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's weird because I was using an online reference and he used begin and end keywords for the case block. I agree that it's an overkill but I am just setting up the code for a larger number of digits :D